# Using a struct which implements a traits from a different crate

Tags: rust

Crate `sha2` contains the type `Sha256` which implements the trait `Digest` defined in the crate `digest`. This trait is also reexported from `sha2`.

I want to write a file which doesn't mention `sha2`, just `digest`:

**merkle_tree.rs:**

```
use digest::Digest;

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MerkleTree<T: Digest> {
    digest: T,
}

impl<T: Digest+Default> MerkleTree<T> {
    pub fn new() -> MerkleTree<T> {
        MerkleTree{ ..Default::default() }
    }
}
```

**main.rs:**

```
extern crate digest;
extern crate sha2;

mod merkle_tree;

use sha2::{Digest, Sha256};
use merkle_tree::MerkleTree;

fn main() {
    let mut mt = MerkleTree::<Sha256>::new();
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

I have the following output:

> error: no associated item named `new` found for type
>   `merkle_tree::MerkleTree<sha2::Sha256>` in the current scope
>   the trait `digest::Digest` is not implemented for `sha2::Sha256`

**Cargo.toml:**

```
[package]
name = "merkle_tree"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Simon Prykhodko <semion.ababo@gmail.com>"]

[dependencies]
digest = "0.4.0"
sha2 = "0.3.0"
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: @ababo Why are you using `sha2 = "0.3.0"`? The latest version is "0.4.2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `digest` you're using and the `digest` the `sha2` crate is using are incompatible.  That they have the same name is irrelevant; as far as the compiler is concerned, you're trying to conflate two entirely different crates.

The quickest way to tell would be to see if `digest` shows up more than once during compilation, or more than once in your `Cargo.lock` file.  You can also verify this manually by looking at crate dependencies.  [`sha2` 0.3.0](https://crates.io/crates/sha2/0.3.0) lists `digest` 0.3 in its dependencies, and 0.3 is not compatible with 0.4.

You need to either downgrade your crate's dependency on `digest`, or upgrade your crate's version of `sha2` to one that uses a newer version of `digest`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and it compiled fine with these dependency versions:

```
[dependencies]
sha2 = "0.4.2"
digest = "0.4.0"
```

Try updating one or both.